# How can I change libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How can I change libraries on Eclipse with Maven builder?

When I change my JRE library by the project properties and then rebuild a project JRE returns to previous version.

How can I add a new library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library is just a dependency. You can add dependencies to you pom-file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This add the junit-library.

Comment: How do I know what is the last version value I could to input?

Comment: Therefor its the best way to use the eclipse-plugin. Open eclipse->doubleClick your pom.xml->choose dependency tab->click add->type in the name you are searching for. Now all available libraries are listed.

Answer (score 1):

> When I change my JRE library by the project properties and then rebuild a project JRE returns to previous version.

This is the case with m2eclipse/m2e, as the Eclipse plugin will revert any changes made to the project properties. In most cases, you're better off specifying the version of the source code, and the target version of the bytecode, via the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin<artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

M2Eclipse/M2E uses these values in the project POM to determine the Java runtime to use for building the project. Considering that it never makes sense (or is impossible) to have multiple Java runtimes for an Eclipse project, you ought to specify the source and target values for the project, either in the project POM or in a parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, then you control all your dependencies via the pom.xml file.  You can either use the [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) to generate the eclipse artifacts, or my preferred approach which is to use the [m2eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).  This plugin makes it easy to keep maven and the eclipse workspace in sync.